# Как сделать так, чтобы часть текста было под частью другого

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3

У меня вопрос, как можно реализовать вот такую вот вещь?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть какой-нибудь вариант сделать это?

Comment: Ну в таком виде, конечно, не без костылей, и то нужно потом ещё потом под адаптив костылями покрывать... Оно того не стоит, если честно)

Comment: `<img src="ну_нафиг_легче_картинкой.png">`

Comment: @VladimirGonchar Я тоже думаю, что не стоит, и видимо придется парочку костылей сделать, ибо так просят. Либо просто не сделаю, вдруг не заметят и так много эффектов (:)
При адаптиве проще выключить скорее, чем делать для него

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME Тут я полностью согласен) 
Надеюсь, что и там сойдет им, просто требуется небольшой параллакс для текста при прокрутке

Comment: О, а параллакс текста "установили шкафов" относительно дырок 3000, вертикально ? Тогда один простой костыль отпадает)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME Не, нужно будет горизонтально, и я видимо по любому через костыль сделаю, который сейчас в ответе и пишу) Вдруг кому - то поможет. 
Возможно это и не параллакс, я просто не знаю, как назвать

Comment: @ГеоргийВениаминов Ну тут по факту текст слоем внизу 3000, текст выше параллаксом, а в самом верху затычка в виде слоя (картинкой скорее всего), которая перекрывает поверху эту цифру.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar Сделаю видимо просто маленький блок, который будет на z-index перекрывать, а по цвету подходить в "3000"

Comment: @VladimirGonchar Ну вот я как раз это и делаю) Спасибо (:)

Comment: @VladimirGonchar
Спасибо за то, что среагировали (:)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME
Спасибо за то, что среагировали (:)

Comment: SVG-хой есть вариант сделать

Answer (score -2):

Как я понял, адекватных способов нет, поэтому вот таким вот костылем буду де делать. Добавил маленький блок, который отцентрировал по высоте, так же как и текста, который по z-index будет выше чем слово "шкаф" и "3000", и покрашу просто блок этот в цвет текста
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]